# PHP Carbon Issue modify time on Daylight Saving Time (DST)

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have issue with Carbon liblary on PHP when modify the day (end day light saving) at UK timezone,
I'm using Carbon version: 1.31.0, PHP version: 5.6.11 on Laravel 5.5

this is my function convert to startOfHour:

```php
    public function getStartHour($timestamp)
    {
        $carbonDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp, 'Europe/London');
        $startHour = $carbonDate->startOfHour()->timestamp;
        return $startHour;
    }

   // Case 1:
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 00:00:00 (am) GMT
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 01:00:00 (am) (Timezone + 1 , On daylight saving)
   $time = $this->getStartHour(1572134400); // 1572138000 (Issue here)
   //My expected: 1572134400

   // Case 2:
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 00:30:00 (am) GMT
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 01:30:00 (am) (Timezone + 1 , On daylight saving)
   $time = $this->getStartHour(1572136200); // 1572138000 (Issue here)
   //My expected: 1572134400

   // Case 3:
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 01:00:00 (am) UCT
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 01:00:00 (am) UK (Timezone + 0)
   $time = $this->getStartHour(1572138000); // 1572138000 - 01:00:00 (Ok)

   // Case 4:
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 01:30:00 (am) UTC
   // Sunday October 27, 2019 01:00:00 (am) (Timezone + 0)
   $time = $this->getStartHour(1572139800); // 1572138000 - 10:00:00 (Ok)
```

4 case these return same result (1572138000). It not right on the real case.

But when I use MomentJs library it converts right my expected
Here is my Js code with Moment

```js
  function getStartHour (timestamp) {
    const m = moment(timestamp * 1000).tz('Europe/London');
    startHour = m.clone().startOf('hour').unix()
    return startHour;
  }
```

What is different on 2 library and how can I fix PHP code return same JS code.
Thank you very much.